# Possible to create a multi-column table from unnest?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to do something like the following in BigQuery?

```
SELECT country, id FROM 
    -- possible to in-line this, with an array or struct even?
    [['us', 1], ['ca',2]] AS country (country, id)
```

Or perhaps there's a better way to do it? Currently the way I'm doing it is the following, but I want to see if I can inline it into the `FROM` instead:

```
WITH country AS (
    SELECT 'us' AS country, 1 as id UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ca', 2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible option would be to make it **ARRAY<STRUCT<>>** type. Consider below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT('us' AS country, 1 AS id),
  STRUCT('ca',2)
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this would be a cross-join on the UNNEST and then filtering by the offset of the array. Note that arrays in this case are columns and not rows:

```
SELECT country, id FROM
  UNNEST(["us", "ca"]) country WITH OFFSET o0, 
  UNNEST([1,2])             id WITH OFFSET o1 
WHERE o0=o1 -- normalize all unnests
```